# Use ghost.py to click a link linking to a javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ghost.py

I have a link (http://bank.hangseng.com/1/PA_1_1_P1/ComSvlet_MiniSite_eng_gif?app=eINVCFundDetailsOV&pri_fund_code=U44217) that I am learning to extract the data inside using python, now I have come to `ghost.py`.

[image]

I want to click the `I Agree`, which is actually not a hyperlink, but a click activating the javascript, and will bring me to the page I need.

I want to use:

```
page, resources = ghost.evaluate(
    "document.getElementById('link').click();", expect_loading=True)
```

As suggested by http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/, but checking the source found that the link do not have an `ID`.

Is it possible, and if yes, how can I use `ghost.py` to extract the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button simply calls the global `agree` function. So you can do this:

```
page, resources = ghost.evaluate("agree()", expect_loading=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector` with css selector. The image has an `alt` attribute with `Agree` as its value. So you can do it as follow.

```
document.querySelector('img[alt=Agree]').click()
```

Comment: I tried `page,resources = ghost.evaluate("document.querySelector('img[alt=Agree]').click()")`, but seems not working